# want to convert pptx or docx to pdf by using microsoft.office.interop, what files should I include for distribution?

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, office-interop

Here is a simple question.

1. I made a VB.Net (framework4.0) software for converting pptx and docx files to PDF files.
2. It uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint and Word for converting files.
3. I want to distribute this software to a closed group.
4. But, when people run the program, it does not work. It crashes.
5. I think that I didn't include proper DLL files.
   (I already included Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll files)

plus, I want to make this program executable on a computer without Microsoft Office. Is it possible to use the Office.Interop on a computer w/o Office?

So, what DLL files should I include for distribution?

or is there any other problem?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you are working with x version take a look at Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office.   Not sure it is will create pdf.   Even Microsoft warns that office was not designed for server side automation.  If you are willing to purchase a tool then look at Aspose.

Comment: You cannot use Office.Interop.* (Excel, Powerpoint, etc..) libraries where MSOffice is not installed. Please see this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/b4026f0b-c3a3-4b80-81df-5175e866ae8f

Answer (score 0):

As Prahlad notes, you cannot use Office.Interop without having Office installed. Office.Interop is just the bridge for your .Net types to consume Office's COM types